# Why is my passport.js Login route not working but register is working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongoose

I was able to successfully create the sign-up and save it in the database. However, I am finding it difficult to implement the login where the user enters their username and password. I do not get any error in the front-end nor the backend.

**This is my passport config**

```
//Session
app.use(session({
    secret: 'secretcode',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(cookieParser('secretcode'))

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session())
passport.use(new passportLocal(customerModel.authenticate()))

passport.serializeUser(customerModel.serializeUser())
passport.deserializeUser(customerModel.deserializeUser())
```

**This is the login route**

```
//Login User
router.post('/login' , passport.authenticate('local' , {failureMessage: true, failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/" }) , authentication.login)
```

**This is the authentication.login part**

```
const login =  (req , res) => {
   res.redirect('http://localhost:3000/')
}
```

**This is the Database Schema**
const passportLocalMongoose = require('passport-local-mongoose')

```
const CustomerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    full_Name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        maxLength: 40
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phone_Number: {
        type: String,
    }
})

// Setting up passport plugin
CustomerSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

module.exports =  mongoose.model('CustomerModel' , CustomerSchema)
```

**This is the code that registers the user**

```
const registerUser =  async (req , res) => {
    const {data} = req.body
    const password = data.password
    //Checks to see if that email is already being used
    Customer.findOne({email: req.body.data.email} , async (err , doc) => {
        if (err) {
            res.send({message: "Error"})
        };
        if(doc) {
            res.send({message: "Exist"})
            console.log(doc)
        };
        //If user does not exist then create one
        if(!doc) {
            const newCustomer = new Customer({
                email: data.email,
                username: data.email,
                full_Name: data.full_Name,
                phone_Number: data.phone_Number,
            })
          await Customer.register(newCustomer , password)
        
            res.json({message: "Success"})
        }
        
    })
}
```

The user registers successfully though because it appears in MongoDb with all the details. I have no idea what I am doing wrong here. Any advice?